# How do I create a static block programmatically?

Tags: 7, blocks

I want to create a static block using a module. I do not want to use the Views module to create a block. Could anyone explain me how to create a static block programmatically?

I have already checked the example modules in Drupal, but it didn't help me much. I have started Drupal module development every recently and I am struggling to do this.

Answer (score 21):

The important hooks in the Block example module are `hook_block_info()` and `hook_block_view()`. The info hook defines your block in the system and the view hook creates the output (html) for your block.

Every module, including yours, will have at least a .info file and a .module file. Drupal.org has some more [documentation about .info files](http://drupal.org/node/542202) that you may find helpful when getting started with modules. Yours really just needs the `name` and `core` entries.

The .module file is where you'll implement your hooks. First, implement `hook_block_info()`, replacing 'hook' in the function name with the name of your module, e.g., `my_module_block_info()`. It should look something like the following.

```
function my_module_block_info() {    
  $blocks['your_block'] = array(
    // info: The name of the block.
    'info' => t('Your Block Name'),
  );

  return $blocks;
}
```

Then, implement your `hook_block_view()` hook to define the static content.

```
function my_module_block_view($delta = '') {
  // The $delta parameter tells us which block is being requested.
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'your_block':
      // Create your block content here
      $block['subject'] = t('Title of first block (example_configurable_text)');
      $block['content'] = 'Your block content, or the result of a function that returns the content';
      break;
  }

  return $block;
}
```

Once you have that in place, you can put your block in any region as you would any other block in Drupal.