# Add block programmatically in the right region

Tags: 7, blocks

I have followed the instruction to create a new block [here](http://kahthong.com/2013/06/create-your-own-custom-drupal-block-programmatically) which is basically the same as [here on SE](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27379/how-do-i-create-a-static-block-programmatically). My block is indeed created but the region is wrongly set to "none" instead of "Content Post".

In my module events.module file:

```
function events_block_info () {
    return [
        'events_list' => [
            'info'       => "Events list",
            'region'     => 'content_post',
            'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_NOTLISTED
        ]
    ];
}

function events_block_view ($delta = '') {
    $result = false;
    if ($delta == 'events_list') {
        /* ... do my stuff .... */
    }

    return $result;
}
```

This creates a block but the region is set to "none". The drawback is I have to go on each environment and change the region manually back to "Content Post". It is inefficient.

I also find it extremely weird that the creation of a block is done this way. I would expect instead that the creation takes place in the module.install file in the hook_install() function. Maybe there is way?

Comment: You have a pluralisation bug (module is called `event`, but you're implementing hooks for a module called `events`). Other than that your method is correct, there's no way to provide blocks through an install file (it's not how Drupal's architecture works yet, in Drupal 8 you don't use the block hooks). `region` is per-theme by the way, and has some extra constraints, the variable desc in the function docs themselves should let you know if those apply to you

Comment: Oops, typo I corrected the events.module in my post here. In my code it was already ok.

Comment: @Clive About "regions", when the `hook_block_info()` is executed, it will add a block for each enabled theme. But in my case all of them are set to the "none" region...

Comment: are you sure the machine name for the region is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to set 'status'.
eg.

```
function events_block_info () {
    return [
        'events_list' => [
            'info'       => "Events list",
            'status'     => TRUE,
            'region'     => 'content_post',
            'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_NOTLISTED
        ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: Is there any way in drupal 8 ?