# How to set Blocks settings in a Drupal Installation Profile?

Tags: 7, blocks, installation-profiles

Is there a way to have my blocks pre-assigned a region and also enabled / disabled in a profile installation? I don't want to go to the structure / block page and assign these blocks individually each time, but would rather have them setup on site installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hook_block_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7.x) inside your custom module to add all of your blocks programmatically. Look at this [SE Post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/157463/add-block-programmatically-in-the-right-region) for an example to use the hook_block_info to assign it to the right region and also enable/disable it by declaring status=>true/false.